# Laravel excel gets saved in storage directory not in storage uploads as my images

Tags: php, laravel

this is my excel controller

```
class ExcelController extends Controller
{
    public function export(Request $request) 
    {
        return Excel::store(new UserProductsExport, 'user_products'. $request->id .'.xlsx');
    }
}
```

My images are working fine, and then i made artisan symlink, images are working fine.
This is the code to upload image

```
public function submitAddProduct(Request $request){

        $data = $request->validate([
            'image' => ['required','image'],
            'image_second' => ['required','image']
        ]);

        // dd(request('image')->store('uploads','public'));

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"));
        $image->save();

        $imagePath2 = request('image_second')->store('uploads','public');

        $image2 = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath2}"));
        $image2->save();

        $dataVal = $request->all();

        $dataVal['image'] = $imagePath;
        $dataVal['image_second'] = $imagePath2;

        // d3d($dataVal);

        $d = Products::create($dataVal);

        $id = $d->id;

        if($id){
            $arr = array('msg' => $id);
        }
        return Response()->json($arr);
    }
```

I want the same thing to happen to excel.
This is the rest of the excel code.
My UserProductsExport class

```
class UserProductsExport implements FromQuery,WithHeadings
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function query()
    {
         $matchThese = ['user_products.user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'user_products.inquiry_flag' => 0];
         return DB::table('user_products')
         ->orderBy('user_products.created_at')
        ->select(
            'inquiries.inquiry_no','users.name as user','users.username as username',
            'users.email','users.id as user_id','users.mobile','products.name as name',
            'units.name as unit_name','subcategories.name as sub_name',
            'user_products.quantity as qty','sizes.name as size_name',
            'products.min_order as min_order'
        )
        ->join('product_prices','user_products.product_price_id', '=', 'product_prices.id')
        ->join('sizes','sizes.id', '=', 'product_prices.size_id')
        ->join('products','products.id', '=', 'product_prices.products_id')
        ->join('units','products.units_id', '=', 'units.id')
        ->join('subcategories','products.subcategories_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('categories','subcategories.categories_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->join('users','user_products.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('inquiries','inquiries.id', '=', 'user_products.inquiry_id')
        ->where($matchThese);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Inquiry No.','User','Username','Email','User ID',
            'Mobile','Product Name','Unit Name','Subcategory Name',
            'Quantity','Size','Min Order'
        ];
    }
}
```

The excel gets created in storage folder, but in my public folder, the symlink to storage doesnt show it.
Now i need to send it thorugh mail.

```
public function userCartMailSend(Request $request)
    {        
        // dd($request['data'][0]['email']);

        Mail::to('')->send(new SendUserSubmitMail($request['data']));   
        return redirect()->route('user.inquiryCart', ['success' => 1]);
    }
```

and SendUserSubmitMail.php

```
public function build()
    {
        // dd($this->data);
        return $this->subject('Subject:User Cart Inquiry')->view('emails.sendUserSubmitMail')
        ->attach(storage_path('app/user_products'. Auth::user()->id .'.xlsx'), [
            'as' => 'user products.xlsx',
            'mime' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        ])
        ->with('data', $this->data);
    }
```

Sorry if its confusing, but the actual question is:
How do i upload it in the uploads folder in storage, and my symlink should show it

Please Help , Thank You